# c# Use Generic as method parameter

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a BaseConfig class that is extended for different projects.  The BaseConfig class contains methods that are common among any project we develop.  BaseConfig is setup like this (just a snippet of the entire class):

```
    public abstract class BaseConfig<T> where T:BaseConfig<T>
    {
        #region Serialized Class Members

        /// <summary>
        /// The License key for this product
        /// </summary>
        public string LicenseKey;

        /// <summary>
        /// Database connection information
        /// </summary>
        public class Database
        {
            public String ServerName;
            public String DatabaseName;
            public bool IntegratedSecurity;
            public String UserName;
            public String Password;
            public String ConnectionStringOptions;
        }
        public Database DatabaseInfo;
....
```

We use this BaseConfig class in conjuntion with a config.xml file that contains information specific to the customer (like databse info).

I would like to create a public method of ConnectToSQL() that can be called by any class extending BaseConfig.

IMPORTANT: ConnectToSQL() will be in a class other than BaseConfig (something like SQLConnectionClass() but within the same project).

I need to setup a method like:

```
private SqlConnection ConnectToSQL(Configuration.BaseConfig<T>.Database dbInfo)
```

and then be called like:

```
SqlConnection _conn = ConnectToSQL(databaseInfo);
```

where databaseInfo comes from a class extending BaseConfig

However, SqlConnection() complains about 'Type or namespace type T cannot be found'.

Anyone know how I could setup this method?

Comment: If `Database` class does not use `T` then why is nested?

Comment: Please explain where exactly is `ConnectToSQL()` located. Add the skeleton code with the rest of the classes (and remove parts that are not needed in the example like `LicenseKey`)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that `Database` shouldn't be within `BaseConfig<T>` anyway - it should be a top-level class. You don't *really* want different types for `BaseConfig<Foo>.Database`, `BaseConfig<Bar>.Database` etc, do you? That's the problem - those are two valid and different types, and your method parameter doesn't express which of them it's interested in.

I'd also strongly recommend using properties instead of those public fields - and probably making the `Database` type immutable.

Comment: BaseConfig is a class that contains information about our product.  There are a number of pieces of data that are consistent across all of our products (database info, license key, etc.) that are loaded from a config.xml file.  The point of BaseConfig is to provide that information similar across all our products.

Comment: Also, the information needs to be updatable via a user interface so I cannot make them immutable.

Comment: None of that suggests that `Database` should be a nested type... and you *can* make `Database` immutable... if you need a new instance with different values, you just create one.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I have moved Database to a top level class and can now call it without <T>.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
public abstract class BaseConfig<T> where T : BaseConfig<T>
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Database connection information
    /// </summary>
    public class Database
    {
        public String ServerName;
        public String DatabaseName;
        public bool IntegratedSecurity;
        public String UserName;
        public String Password;
        public String ConnectionStringOptions;
    }
    public Database DatabaseInfo { get; set; }

    public abstract SqlConnection ConnectToSQL(Database info);
}

public class MyConfig : BaseConfig<MyConfig>
{
    public override SqlConnection ConnectToSQL(Database info)
    {
         ...
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cfg=new MyConfig();
        cfg.ConnectToSQL(cfg.DatabaseInfo);
    }
}
```